# XML parsing and automation

Tags: c#, xml, selenium, linq-to-xml

I have never really had the need to use `XML` in addition to the automation that I write for work.  Maybe I have been doing it wrong or maybe I have just been ...lucky?

That being said, I am having some troubles with parsing an `XML`file.  The structure of the `XML` looks like this:

```
// I have removed the username and passwords as they are sensitive
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Logins>
   <Login>
      <Username>xxx</Username>
      <Password>xxx</Password>
   </Login>
...
</Logins>
```

Simple enough.  What I need to do is pull the username and password from each node and put them into two separate variables.  After that, I have some automated code that finds the 3 elements (username, password, submit button), and interacts with them accordingly to log me in.  I then do a smoke test to check for an image and close the browser.  That code is here:

```
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"userNameInput")).SendKeys(userName.ToString());
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"passwordInput")).SendKeys(passWord.ToString());
chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"submitButton")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(10);
bool isVisible = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"logoImage")).Displayed;
```

As you may be able to ascertain, the variables I need to use are, `userName` and `passWord`.  The code I have tried, to no avail, (among other attempts) is here:

```
XDocument rootElement = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Test Data.xml");

IEnumerable<string> textSegment =
   from segment in rootElement.Descendants("Username")
   select (string)segment;

var userName = textSegment;
```

The output I am getting is this:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.String]

That is the literal output that is being written/sent to the username field, and I am completely at a loss as to what I am doing wrong at this point.  I know I am doing something wrong when it comes to parsing the `XML`.

Comment: Does **var userName = textSegment.ToList()** get what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = rootElement.Descendants("Login").Select(lg =>
                   new {
                         user = lg.Element("Username").Value,
                         password = lg.Element("Password").Value
                        });
```

You tried to convert a object of type XElement to string ,you should take its value instead.

Comment: This got my thinking on the right path.  I will post my full answer code once I complete it.  Thanks so much, @CPR43!

Answer (score 1):

So, with the help of **CPR43** and **Stinky Towel** (thank you both), I was able to come up with this solution to my problem:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace MCESA_SmokeTest
{
   public class SmokeTest
   {
      IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\xxxxx\Selenium Stuff\Drivers");

      [Test]
      public void NavigateToHomePageInProduction()
      {
         chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://xxx.xxx.xxx/XXXX");
         chromeDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

         XDocument rootElement = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Test Data.xml");

         var result = rootElement.Descendants("Login").Select(lg =>
              new
              {
                 user = lg.Element("Username").Value,
                 password = lg.Element("Password").Value
              });

         foreach (var temp in result)
         {
            chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"userNameInput")).SendKeys(temp.user);
            chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"passwordInput")).SendKeys(temp.password);
            chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"submitButton")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            bool isVisible = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"logoImage")).Displayed;
            isVisible = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName(@"Header_mcesa")).Displayed;
            chromeDriver.FindElement(By.Id(@"logout")).Click();
         }
         chromeDriver.Quit();
      }  
   }
}
```

Hopefully this can help anyone else that is new to `LinQ-to-XML` like I am.